# Sitecore Redirect urls

Tags: .htaccess, iis, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I am working on 301 url redirects, i tried some Sitecore redirect modules before, but i am looking for recommended approach, actually i have requirements to remove language code "en" from the URL if the language is English and keep it for other languages, i did that in link manager and for example when the user click on about us link, it will take him to the page without language code like this:

> www.mywebsite.com/about-us

but still i can access the url with language code manually like this :

> www.mywebstie.com/en/about-us

so now i have two urls to the same page. and this is not recommended for the SEO. and in the end i want only one url for each page.

another example also, about us can be access with hyphen

> www.mywebstie.com/about-us

and with space

> www.mywebstie.com/about us

what is the best approach to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a Canonical is an option, `<link id="Canonical" rel="canonical" href="/about-us/" />` then you SEO problem is gone.

Or just creat the redirect in your MasterPage somethings like this:

```
string goodUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item);
if (goodUrl != Request.Path)
{
    Response.RedirectPermanent(goodUrl);
}
```

Beside the variant you already mentioned, this will also work /about-us.aspx and /about-us.ashx. Other option is, You can certainly also solve this in the httpRequestBegin pipeline, ItemResolver.

Answer (score 1):

There is wide range of options how you can achieve required behavior:

1. You could configure your Sitecore website

   Configure LinkManager (Sitecore.config): Change settings in default LinkProvider. For excluding language from URLs set languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="queryString".

   Configure encodeNameReplacements (Sitecore.config): add this rule

   <replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-">

   to replace spaces with dashes.
2. Use [canonical links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)
3. Write [your own LinkProvider](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2015/02/yalp-yet-another-link-provider-for-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx) for your purpose
4. Install and configure IIS extensions that could redirect your requests.

   e.g.: [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), [Ionic's Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) or [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) But [be careful](http://sitecorevn.blogspot.com/2016/04/sitecore-and-iis-url-rewrite-module.html) if you plan to use this modules on CM instance.

I would recommend you try to configure your Sitecore LinkManager provider, encodeNameReplacement rules (item 1 in list) and  add canonical links (item 2 in list). It seems that it will be enough for your task.

If configuration and canonical links will not be enough, you could extend default Sitecore behavior(item 3 in list) or install and configure IIS modules(item 4 in list).

Comment: I already implemented custom link provider to solve the language issue, to remove the en from url if the language is English and this is fine, when i click on any link on english language it will take the user to the url without "en", but if the user navigate manually to the url with language code, the url will work. instead it should be redirect to the orginal url. this is the main issue. and i can't use IIS URL rewriter in this case as the sitecore language resolver  is coming after iis processing.

Comment: The same issue  for replace space with dash. actually I have created event on item save/update to replace space in item name  with "-", but if you have display name with space, and you navigate the item url with display name it will work. so about-us and "about us" both will be accesible in the url

Comment: 1) If all your links will be formed with configured link manager and encode name replacement then search engine crawler will not know about other link types.
2) If you want exact 302 redirect then your should add your own processor to <httpRequestBegin> pipeline and redirect users if URL match some rules.

Comment: About IIS URL Rewrite: It is quite intelligent, you can write rule to move language from path "en" to query string "?sc_lang=/en/". In this case you will not have any problems with Sitecore language resolver